# Sheaf on Empty Set in Zariski Topology over Spectrum of Integers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, sheaf-theory

I am confused about how to understand the sheaf on empty set (as an open subset) of the Zariski Topology over the Spec(Z), which is generated by the additive identity zero in Z.  The sheaf I have in mind is the structure sheaf sending open sets to local rings.  I read related pages and I cannot understand how sheaf over empty set is a terminal object.  Is this terminal object an additive/multiplicative identity of the ring?  Is terminal object an element of the local ring?

Comment: the sheaf gluing axiom forces any sheaf to evaluate the empty set to the terminal object, i.e. the object in the category with a unique arrow to it from very other object. A sheaf of rings must therefore take the empty set to the terminal ring, which is the trivial ring. The trivial ring is the ring that contains only zero. Zero is an element of every ring.